# Translating SQL query to Doctrine2 DQL

Tags: sql, symfony, group-by, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to translate this (My)SQL to DQL

```
SELECT content, created, AVG(rating)
FROM point
GROUP BY DAY(created)
ORDER BY created ASC
```

And I'm stuck at GROUP BY part, apparently DAY/WEEK/MONTH isn't recognized as valid "function".

**[Semantical Error] line 0, col 80 near '(p.created) ORDER': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification variable.**

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('p')
       ->select('p')
       ->groupBy('DAY(p.created)')
       ->orderBy('p.created', 'ASC')
```

**Q: Is it possible to create this kind of query with query builder, or should I use native query?**

Comment: According to the DQL documentation, you would need to add a user defined function to get this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to use custom DAY/WEEK/MONTH user functions in GROUP BY queries in Doctrine 2.1.?, only SELECT queries are supported (not sure for 2.2.? branch), so I ended up using native query, and everything works fine.

**Quick overview of the code:**

```
// creating doctrines result set mapping obj.
$rsm = new Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();

// mapping results to the message entity
$rsm->addEntityResult('Omglol\AppBundle\Entity\Message', 'm');
$rsm->addFieldResult('m', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('m', 'content', 'content');
$rsm->addFieldResult('m', 'rating', 'rating');
$rsm->addFieldResult('m', 'created', 'created');

$sql = "SELECT id, content, AVG(rating) as rating, created
        FROM message 
        WHERE domain_id = ? 
        GROUP BY WEEK(created)";

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $domainId);
$query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the same topic in :
[Link to google group](https://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/0b9f8c56e1408556)